# create an array using dma , write it to file and display all data of file

Tags: c++, dma

I have tried to create an array dynamically , write it to a file and at last try to display all data from file but while running it accept the data but it stop working while displaying all data from file.how can we dynamically create an string array , write it to a some data file like "test.txt" and at last display all that  data from file "test.txt" in c++? please help.

Comment: That code you wrote? Yeah, it goes up there in the question, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik certainly not what you and 99% of the rest of the engineering world think it is (direct memory access); the OP is using that acronym to describe *dynamic memory allocation*.